# How can I ask my middle-aged cat if she'd accept another in the house?

Tags: cats, multi-pet-families, adoption, introducing-pets

Hazel is now around 12; middle-aged for a cat. She lived with her sibling Harry until we lost him, but she's had me to herself for several years now.

It isn't clear whether Harry was a special case because she'd grown up with him, or if she'd be generally open to the idea of having another cat around.

I know best practices for introducing a new cat (see other questions)... but I'd sorta like to find a way to ask her opinion first, and I don't want to be the guy who adopts a cat from the shelter only to return it if he runs into difficulties.

Best thought I've had would be to offer to foster for a few weeks with the understanding that it's partly a trial run, since fosters turning into adoptions is a lot less fraught than adoptions turning into fosters.

Any better ideas? Or am I overthinking this, and should I count on Hazel being generally friendly if I bring in another cat that's generally friendly?

Comment: I don't know how to ask a cat and I think that fostering can be stressful for the fostered cat, so I'm not a fan. But from my personal experience you'd have the best chances if both cats have a similar personality. If Hazel is a calm and cuddly cat and you adopt a young, playful kitten, I expect conflicts. If you adopt an equally calm, maybe even shy cat, they can probably adapt better to each other. But as always, there is no guarantee. Some cats just don't like each other.

Comment: The shelters where I life have the option to make a "meet and greet" before adoption. Some let you take your cat to them, others let you take the new cat to your home (some with company of a shelter staff member). Maybe you can ask for this at your shelter? I think a serious shelter want the animals to have a long term home, and help to find it in many ways.